# Is it possible to change the Japanese Kana keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, input-source, japanese

Windows' Japanese IME and and Google's Japanese IME both use Layout1 for Kana mode. However, macOS's Japanese IME uses Layout2. Notice the different locations for　ろ、む、へ, and some symbols. Is there any way to use Layout1 for macOS's Japanese IME?

Layout1

[image: Layout1]

Layout2

[image: Layout2]

Comment: If you know japanese, try also at   https://discussionsjapan.apple.com/welcome

Comment: PS My usual recommendation for anyone who does not like something about Apple's Japanese IM is to use Google's instead.  http://m10lmac.blogspot.com/2017/05/macos-alternative-input-methods-for.html

Comment: I might go there and ask. But I am afraid that there probably are fewer users than here. I have already been using Google's Japanese IME on macOS, but since Apple's has some features that Google has not, I wondered if I could just fix the layout.

Comment: I'd be interested in hearing what features google is lacking.  You can try looking inside system/library/input methods/japaneseim.app for a keyboard to modify, but I haven't found any.